# Maven - how to change pom.xml to use jars installed into local repo?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I have successfully installed a JAR into the Maven local repository. I edit my pom.xml to include these lines:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jcrontab</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcrontab</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>[somepath]/jcrontab-4.0.0.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

But, after installing with `install:install-file`, I think these lines are redundant. I just use them to install and when I want to "use" the jar, they are useless because the jar is in the local repo.

So I changed them to:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jcrontab</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcrontab</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The same form as those dependencies that exist in the remote Maven central repo. But now Eclipse complains about:

```
missing artifact: org.jcrontab:jcrontab:jar:4.0.0
```

And in the Maven dependencies library in Java Build path, I see red cross on the jar, saying:

> jcrontab-4.0.0.jar - D:\desarrollo\eclipse-jee-mars-x86_64\eclipse\${maven.home}\m2\repository\org\jcrontab\jcrontab\4.0.0 (missing)

Under this dir, I only see:

```
jcrontab-4.0.0.jar.lastUpdated  jcrontab-4.0.0.pom.lastUpdated
```

And no jar is there. But other dependencies jars in this Eclipse repo are in their places.

As I examine my maven home repo (`<maven-installation-dir>/m2/repository`), the jar is installed there. But in the repo under Eclipse dir, the jar is missing.

I am confused.

1. If the installation of external jar generates a JAR under Maven installation repo, why does Eclipse "Maven dependencies" library points to a repo under Eclipse dir? The `{$maven.home}` directory smells bad to me.
2. Am I supposed to change the dependencies of local installed jars like what I did?

---

As suggested, I execute the command of install:install-file, and I get:

```
C:\Windows\System32>mvn install:install-file -Dfile="D:\desarrollo\Java environment\lib\jcrontab-4.0.0.jar" -DgroupId=org.jcronta
b -DartifactId=jcrontab -Dversion=4.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Installing D:\desarrollo\Java environment\lib\jcrontab-4.0.0.jar to D:\desarrollo\Java environment\lib\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin\..\m2\repository\org\jcrontab\jcrontab\4.0.0\jcrontab-4.0.0.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.597 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-03T14:27:48+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/114M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

> The same form as those dependencies that exist in the remote Maven central repo.

But jcrontab doesn't exist on maven central.

See yourself on maven central: https://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|jcrontab

So you need to install the jar into your local repository if you want to use it like another dependency. You can do that like that:

```
    mvn install:install-file -Dfile=jcrontab-4.0.0.jar -DgroupId=org.jcrontab -DartifactId=jcrontab -Dversion=4.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

See also the maven documentation here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Comment: So, at first, I shouldn't change my pom.xml, because if I edit it as others, it will only resolve against remote repo, and no way it will resolve against local repo, right? But I think add "install-file" part into my final pom.xml is ugly... How can I make it resolve as well as against local repo?

Comment: maven resolves dependencies first from local repo, and if not present from maven central (or others configured maven repositories). But you can use the flag -o (offline) to force maven to resolve only from local repository.
Here, your problem is that you don't have the jar into your local repository

Comment: Thanks. But I have installed it into maven local repo, as I stated at the first line of OP. The jar is there. But Eclipse seems unable to find it.

Comment: Your jar is not correctly installed, try to use the command i put in my answer

Comment: I did what you say and I have updated my question with the output. Please let me explain: the jar is installed in **Maven** repo under Maven installation dir, but not in **Eclipse Maven repo** under Eclipse installation dir. See this line in my OP: `jcrontab-4.0.0.jar - D:\desarrollo\eclipse-jee-mars-x86_64\eclipse\${maven.home}\m2\repository\org\jcrontab\jcrontab\4.0.0 (missing)`. It's under Eclipse installation repo. The `${maven.home}` part seems wrong and I want to know why.